# C++ ( Arduino ) pass Pointer Address Variable to Function

Tags: c++, function, pointers, arduino

Moin Moin,

I'd like to pass a variable Pointer Address to a Function to get the bytes of the variable in a buffer - see code snippet!
This version of the code works ... but I like to skip the additional address definition before the function call.

Thank you very much!

```
float f = 133.2342;
int x = 12345;
byte buffer[8] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};

void var_to_byte(const int anz, int* var_split, int* buffer)
{
  for (int i=0;i<8;i++) buffer[i]=0;
  for (int i=0;i<anz;i++)
  {
    buffer[i]=var_split[i];
  }
}

void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  
// I like to skip these lines
  int z = &f;
  int y = &buffer;
// call the function with var_to_byte(sizeof(f),&f,&buffer); is not working

  var_to_byte ( sizeof(f),z,y); // this works !!!!
  Serial.print("Buffer: ");
  for (int i=0;i<8;i++)
  {
    if (buffer[i]<0x10)
    {
      Serial.print("0");
    }
    Serial.print(buffer[i],HEX);
  }
  Serial.println();
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
```

I don't know how to solve this problem ... and yes I'm new to C++ and/or Arduino ....

Answer (score 1):

It cannot work because the types do not match in the slightest.

You can serialise a value into an existing buffer like so:

```
// if out is too small, this will blow up (undefined behaviour)
inline void serialise(float const f, std::byte* out) {
  auto const* raw = reinterpret_cast<std::byte const*>(&f);
  std::copy(raw, raw+sizeof(float), out);
}
```

But you can also avoid having to pass in the buffer:
(see below if you want to avoid `std::array`)

```
#include <array>
inline auto serialise(float const f) {
  std::array<std::byte, sizeof(f)> out;
  auto const* raw = reinterpret_cast<std::byte const*>(&f);
  std::copy(raw, raw+sizeof(f), out.begin());
  return out; // copy elided by all sensible compilers
}

// usage
int main() {
  float const f = 3.14f;
  auto const ser = serialise(f);
  // do stuff with ser
  for (auto const x: ser) {
    if (x<0x10)
      Serial.print("0");
    Serial.print(x,HEX);
  }
  Serial.println();
}
```

Of course, you can generalise `serialise` to any type:

```
template <typename T>
inline auto serialise(T const& t) {
  // pretty much the same code only with T instead of float
}
```

---

Edit:

If you have to avoid using the standard library, you can also pass a sized raw-array reference:

```
auto serialise(float const f, std::byte (&out)[sizeof(float)]) {
  auto const* raw = reinterpret_cast<std::byte const*>(&f);
  std::copy(raw, raw+sizeof(f), out);
  return out; // copy elided by all sensible compilers
}
```

Comment: This is Arduino C++ so using the standard library is problematic.

Comment: @john I haven't done much uC lately and no Arduino; What's the problem with `std::array`? It never allocates. It's a thin wrapper around a raw array.

Comment: I don't know the details but many Arduino C++ users complain when given answers using the standard library. IDK, maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: @john Fair enough. See my edit.

Comment: @john Oh wait, did you also mean to include `std::copy` in that?

Comment: `std::copy` and `std::byte`. AFAIK Arduino C++ users have a limited standard library available. It does include `std::string` but not much else. But I'm going to see if I can find some actual facts instead of my speculations.

Comment: Hard to get a straight answer, but see [here](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/24790/is-the-c-stl-fully-supported-on-arduino) for example. TLDR no standard library as standard, but some partial implementations exist.

Answer (score 0):

The types in your code don't make sense. If you want to populate a buffer of bytes then why does your function say this `int* buffer`? That's a buffer of `int` not `byte`.

The simple approach is to use the standard library function `memcpy` for copying bytes. No need for your own function for this standard task.

```
memcpy(buffer, &f, sizeof f); // copy the bytes of f to buffer
```

`memcpy` is declared in the header file `<string.h>`

Comment: That works thank you! My thoughts of `int* buffer` was that the pointer address is an int ....